# Relative path is not working properly in webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader

Webpack is providing wrong URL for CSS file while running using nw.js.

> file:///C://Application/dirA/dirB/dirC/dirA/dirB/dirC/node_modules/style-small/style-small.min.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Relative path *dirA/dirB/dirC* is getting added twice

Refer below directory structure and webpack-config.js

```
C:\<path>\Application
               |- nw.exe
               |- webpack.config.js
               |- dirA
                    |- dirB
                         |- dirC
                              |- node_modules
                              |- index.html
                              |- bundle.js  
                              |- entry.js
```

webpack-config.js

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {

  entry: './dirA/dirB/dirC/entry.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dirA/dirB/dirC',
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /node_modules/, loader: "imports-loader?define=>undefined" },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.css'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "./dirA/dirB/dirC/node_modules"),
    ],

  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  target: 'node-webkit',

  externals: {
    'slack-node' : 'Slack-node',
  },

  node: {
   __dirname: true
  },
};
```

entry.js

```
.......
require('style-small'); // CSS file from node_modules
require('style-extra-small'); // CSS file from node_modules

window.onload = function() {
..................
}
```